# How to install using python poetry and mention the fivetran dbt package salesforce_formula_utils in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, dagster, fivetran

Trying to install the fivetran dbt package: "salesforce_formula_utils" in my DBT-Dagster project.

The item shown below is not a component of PyPI; rather, it is a repository given by Fivetran. Since it lacks an installation setup file, I have listed it as a dependant package in PyProject.toml using Python poetry.

I gave the package's git location as shown below, but it's still not installing and giving the following error.

Any suggestion would be appriciated.

pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
fivetran-salesforce-formula-utils = { git = "https://github.com/fivetran/salesforce_formula_utils.git", tag = "v0.9.0" }

Error:
poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file
Warning: poetry.lock is not consistent with pyproject.toml. You may be getting improper dependencies. Run `poetry lock [--no-update]` to fix it.

Unable to determine package info for path: /workspaces/gdp-transforms-us/.venv/src/salesforce_formula_utils

Command ['/tmp/tmp_jtqwzzp/.venv/bin/python', '-'] errored with the following return code 1

No fallback setup.py file was found to generate egg_info.

Answer (score 1):

Poetry is used for managing Python dependencies, and it primarily deals with packages available on PyPI or other compatible sources. Meaning that you would define stuff that needs to be installed with `python -m pip install ...`. For instance, your `pyproject.toml` will most probably have lower level stuff such as the Python version and the dbt-adapter version:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.11,<3.12"
dbt-snowflake = "1.6.3"
```

On the other hand, dbt packages are installed via dbt CLI through the `dbt deps` command. The place where you define these packages is the `dbt-packages` directory within your dbt project:

```yaml
# this is my packages.yml

packages:
  - package: fivetran/dbt_salesforce_formula_utils
    version: [">=0.9.0", "<0.10.0"]
```

So, to my understanding, defining a dbt package within a `pyproject.toml` might not be correct.

Comment: That's awesome and I have tried this approach without the poetry in my local environment but still wondering about the better approach. The same tried in Codespace successfully appreciates the suggestion.